# In accordance with Noah's prophecy concerning Shem, Ham and Japheth, is there any significance in the number of sons recorded in the text?

Tags: genesis, word-study, noah

> Genesis 10:2  (NKJV)
>
> The sons of Japheth were Gomer, Magog, Madai, Javan,
>   Tubal, Meshech, and Tiras.
>
> v6)  The sons of Ham were Cush, Mizraim,
>   Put, and Canaan.
>
> v22) The sons of Shem were Elam, Asshur, Arphaxad,
>   Lud, and Aram.

In this passage, Shem whose God is the LORD (Yahweh) has Five sons.

Japheth who will be enlarged by God has Seven sons

Ham who is the younger son in Gen 9:24 (where younger is the hebrew word "qaton" meaning insignificant) ends up having Four sons.

I wonder if the difference in their number of sons is related to Noah's prophecy in Gen 9:25-27.

Comment: These are only the recorded names. Genesis 11:11 says, "*And Shem lived after he begat Arphaxad five hundred years, and begat sons and daughters*". The same would have been true of the other sons of Noah. So, your question should be, "In accordance with Noah's prophecy concerning Shem, Ham and Japheth, is there any significance in the number of sons **recorded in the text**?"

Comment: The idea that Shem only had two sons in his 500 years after having Arphaxad, or his father, Noah, living 600 years only having three sons then a further 300+ years and not having any others, is far fetched. One needs to be careful how such things are read.

Comment: The connection of Gen 9:25-27 to Gen 10:2 is weak for Noah's prophecy only named one out of the four sons of Ham. Also the number of one generation did not determine the number of coming generations.